# When running a function multiple times how do i save the data after each time it is run?

Tags: python

I've tried many times to do this but after each time it is run the variable i made is still set to 0 but after the last time it is run it is set to 1, a way to do this? here's my code so far.

how do i make it so whenever it loops through the next time the value of amount won't be 0

EDIT 1:
new code:

````
                global amount, penny, pebble, rock, bottle, cap, ten_dollar_note, percentage
                pebble = 0
                rock = 0
                bottle = 0
                cap = 0
                penny = 0
                ten_dollar_note = 0
                amount = 0

                percentage = random.randint(0, 100)

                if percentage <= 10:
                    ten_dollar_note += 1
                    amount += 1
                elif percentage <= 35:
                    rock += 1
                    amount += 1
                elif percentage <= 45:
                    pebble += 1
                    amount += 1
                elif percentage <= 65:
                    cap += 1
                    amount += 1
                elif percentage <= 85:
                    penny += 1
                    amount += 1

            random_percentage = random.randint(15,31)
            times = 0

            while times != random_percentage:
                overworld_choose()
                times += 1
                amount_one = amount```
````

the problem now is that each loop i want to add the value of the function before to it so i tried to do amount_one = amount + 0 but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: One thing: A function should get every value it needs via parameters and give back the values with `return`. Try to write your code without `global`.

Comment: @Matthias wdym so i should put the variables in the parameters and return all the variables

Comment: Using `global` is entirely correct according to the fact you wrote `variable += 1`, this is precisded in the well known book *Fluent Python*. So this is not the issue at all.

Comment: @AvyWam how would i go by trying to fix this then?

Comment: @China3232323 be patient I am trying to know why, but clearly using `global` is you did was a good practice contrary to what someone else told you.

Comment: @AvyWam i am confused how to even save it after every time

Comment: According to your code `amount` is more than `0`. I just wrote `print(amount, penny, rock)` just below `times += 1` the given outputs are: `1 1 0`, `2 2 0`,...`28 28 0`. Of course the outputs are different from one to another execution because it's based on random, but I don't see particular issue to "how do i make it so whenever it loops through the next time the value of amount won't be 0", it is different from 0 according to the values given randomly.

Comment: im confused... d

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. `amount` does change. Please provide a [mre]. You can [edit] the question. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: Why putting `global` before creating the variables ? You should use `global` to modify a nonlocal variable in a function (I don't go in details). You were right the first time I told you, but here this is useless and has no sense. Besides to write `amount_one = amount` will change nothing clearly. Moreover you still write `overworld_choose()` while this is not defined. Without disrespect this is messy and we cannot help even doing our best.

Comment: @China3232323 Please fix the indenting. and where's the function declaration?

Comment: @AvyWam I didn't say the not-usage of `global` would solve the problem. In that case I would have written an answer. I just wanted to say that using `global` is considered bad programming style in more than 99,9% of all cases where it is used. This is one of those cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it all i had to do is add a variable outside of the functoin called new_amount and make this the while loop:

````
 while times != random_percentage:
        overworld_choose()
        times += 1
        amount1 = amount
        new_amount += amount```
````